# How to find average in this case?

Tags: experimental-physics, density, data-analysis

If we have 10 trials of measuring density each repeated three times. How can we find average? Do we take the average of each trial and then find the average of the averages? Would this be physically logical?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you taking 30 measurements of density? Why aren't 3 enough?

Answer (score 1):

As long as all 30 measurements were measuring the same thing (as opposed to 3 measurement of one value, modifying something, then 3 more measurements), then they all have equal weight and there is no need to take the average of averages.

Comment: I am sorry John, I don't understand very clearly what is in parentheses. May you say it in other words?

Comment: Say you want to measure the position of a cart on a track. You can use two rulers to find it's position at any one time. Then at a later time, after it's moved, you use those same two rulers to get a measurement of it's new position. You shouldn't average all four measurements because the first two are not the same quantity as the second two. The fact that you're taking ten sets of measurements three times each looks more like you're measuring ten different things and I wanted to cover that.